# adding data to resource and head sections in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm in the process of customizing fullcalendar (premium) into a rostering system.

As such I need to show the total No. of shifts and hours per date. This also goes for each row/employee.

Getting the data is not a problem. My issue is adding the icons and data to the areas marked in red in my screenshot below.

If you have any suggestions I would be forever grateful.

This shows you what I'm aiming to create, in terms of the icons and data I need to put into the header:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FullCalendar: Show total added event hours for each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970249/fullcalendar-show-total-added-event-hours-for-each)

Comment: Assuming this is fullCalendar version 5 then you can inject content into the headers with https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slot-render-hooks and into the resources with https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource-render-hooks. Does that help? It isn't clear specifically where you're having a problem